# Add hyperlink to columns in DataTables

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, datatables

> Im newbie in using DataTables, I created a webpage that uses
>   client-side processing to load the data. I want to add Hyperlink in my
>   columns using "**columns.render**" to view the details in entire row where
>   the value of **ID/pk** corresponds to the hyperlinked text, so that if a
>   user click the Id/hyperlink in ID columns they would be rerouted to a
>   separate page, "**VM/Details/(id/pk)**". How I fixed this?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#vmtable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": false,
        "scrollX": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/vm/?format=datatables",
            "type": "POST"
            },
        "columns": [
            {"data":"id",
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                if(type === 'display'){
                    data = '<a href="VM/Details/' + data.id + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }
                return data;
                }
            },
            {"data": "Activity_Id"},
            {"data":"NO"},
            {"data":"First_name"},
            {"data":"Last_name"}
        ]
    });
```

**html**

```
<table id="vmtable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" data-server-side="false" data-ajax="/api/vm/?format=datatables">
                   <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Activity No</th>
                            <th>NO</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
</table>
```

> Path that I want to rerouted after click the hyperlink

```
path('VM/Details/<int:pk>', vmDetails.as_view(), name='vm_details'),
```

> But I got an error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/VM/Details/undefined
```

> "/api/vm/?format=datatables"

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Activity_Id": "VML2020-000001",
            "NO": "000001",
            "First_name": "Jason",
            "Last_name": "Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show us the view code for `/api/vm/?format=datatables`. Issue is data.id is undefined

Answer (score 1):

The `data` parameter passed to the `render` function of a column pertains to the data of the cell itself (e.g. `id`). If you need access to the whole data for that row, use `row` instead.

In other words, for that column, `data` == `row.id`

Applying to your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        ...
        "columns": [
            {
            "data":"id",
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                if(type === 'display'){
                    data = '<a href="VM/Details/' + data + '">' + row.Activity_Id + '</a>';
                    }
                return data;
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    });
```

Source: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render